# Not able to map drive to Azure File Storage share and port 445 open

Tags: file, azure, storage, share

Has anyone outside of Msft been able to map a drive to the new preview of Azure File Storage shares without having a VPN? Our IT guy has verified that 445 is open outbound and we even contacted Comcast to verify that they are not blocking the traffic.

This is the command we are using and the error we get...

```
C:\Users\johndoe>net use Y: \\\\myfileshare.file.core.windows.net\\clientapps /u:myfileshare mystoragekey

System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

AzCopy works fine, but that uses `https`. We have tried from Windows 2012 Server and a Surface with Windows 8.1. Both support SMB3.0.

Should we be able to test telnet to `myfileshare.file.core.windows.net` on port `445`?

Comment: I used the command above and was able to map the network drive. Two quick questions - 1) Is `myfileshare` the name of your storage account? 2) Does `clientapps` share exist in that storage account? I can reproduce this error if I specify a share that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was working on Windows 8 and 10, but not Windows 8.1

I had to change the Group Policy for LAN Manager authentication level to: Send NTLMv2 responses only. I got this info from this MS answer.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2ab0015-e7f7-4efb-b539-e1083d5a9d1b/azure-storage-file-service-for-onpremise-net-use-error-53?forum=windowsazuredata

I case you don't know how to open up the policy editor, see this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: My bad. Fixed (I hope). Not sure if it is worth down voting though. This solution really worked for us, and it is hardly anywhere else mentioned this might only occur on specifically Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. It happens that I can use the command NET USE in some hosts, while in others it gives me an error 53. On another host I actually get an access denied error.

It works fine in one Windows 10. On another 3 I've tried it does not work fine. It also works fine on a Windows 2008 R2 used as a dev environment, but it does not work on others.

I have no problem when using Azure Powershell CMDlets though.

Answer (score 0):

When I called Comcast they told me 445 was blocked. I created an azure vm and confirmed the command was correct. Was able to map my drive fine within Azure. took the same command on-premise and kept getting the same error you mentioned. I would double check that comcast really has the open.